# Can I use .apply() similar to .iterrows()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I like to make a somewhat easy calculation on the rows of my data frame and used to use `.iterrows()` but the the operation is very slow. Now I wonder if I can use `.apply()` to achieve the same thing to get it done faster. It could also be that there is a totally differnt option, which I'm just not aware of or have not thought about.

Here is what I want to do:
Assuming the following dataframe

|  | ID_1 | ID_2 | ... | ID_n | mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 15 | ... | 12 | 7 |
| 1 | 20 | 10 | ... | 17 | 21 |

I like to check for each row which element is larger than the mean of the entire row (already given in the mean column). If the value is larger I like to get the part of the ID after the `_` (column name) for this entry and finally sum up all the values that are larger than the row mean and safe it to a new column.

Thanks for any help.

I already tried to use
`df.apply(lamda row: my_func(row), axis=1)`

```
def my_func(x):
    id = str(x.index)
    if x[x.name] > (df['mean'].iloc[x.name]):
        sum( x )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `.melt` with `.loc`, `.groupby` and `.join` to get your values.

```
#we need the index to rejoin later
df1 = pd.melt(df,id_vars='mean',ignore_index=False).reset_index()

con = df1['value'].gt(df1['mean']) # your conditional.

df_new = df.join(df1.loc[con].assign(_id=df1['variable'].str.split('_').str[1]
         ).groupby('index')\
          .agg(_id=('_id',list),computed_mean=('value','sum')) 
       )
```

---

```
print(df_new)

   ID_1  ID_2  ID_n  mean        _id  computed_mean
0    10    15    12     7  [1, 2, n]           37.0
1    20    10    17    21        NaN            NaN
```

If we look into `df1` & `con` we can see the records we are interested in.

```
   index  mean variable  value
0      0     7     ID_1     10
1      1    21     ID_1     20
2      0     7     ID_2     15
3      1    21     ID_2     10
4      0     7     ID_n     12
5      1    21     ID_n     17


print(con)

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```

### Option 2

If you don't need the `IDs` as a list then a simple `sum` and `mask` will do.

```
df['computed_mean'] = df.mask(df.lt(df['mean'],axis=0)).drop('mean',axis=1).sum(axis=1)

   ID_1  ID_2  ID_n  mean  computed_mean
0    10    15    12     7           37.0
1    20    10    17    21            0.0
```

Comment: Thanks this option also works and having the list of the ID's in a column is very helpful for later calculations.

Comment: @SnowGepard glad it helped, would recommend accepting the answer that does not use any python for loops as those are considered an anti pattern with the pandas API

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
d = np.array([  [10,15,12,7],
                [20,10,17,21]])
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=["ID_1","ID_2","ID_3","mean"])

N = 3

def my_func(row):
    s = 0
    for i in range(1,N+1):
        if row[f"ID_{i}"] > row["mean"]:
            s += row[f"ID_{i}"]

    return s

df["sum_lrgr_mean"] = df.apply(lambda row: my_func(row), axis=1)
df
```

This will produce:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful and I could solve my problem. It is also reasonably fast.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want speed, you can move from pandas to numpy arrays as such:

```
N = np.array(
    [
        [10, 15, 12],
        [20, 10, 17]
    ]
)
M = np.array(
    [
        [7],
        [21]
    ]
)

np.sum(N*(N>M),axis=1)
```

Which will produce this array:

```
array([37,  0])
```